# Azure Functions OpenApi extensions OAuth/OICD authentication

Tags: azure-functions, swagger-ui, openapi, auth0

I'm trying to have my Swagger UI page allow authentication against my Auth0 account. To make Auth0 produce the correct type of token one is required to send an audience with the request.

At the moment I have this decoration on my function.

```
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "name" })]
        [OpenApiParameter(name: "name", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "The **Name** parameter")]
        [OpenApiSecurity("oidc_auth",
                         SecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect,
                         OpenIdConnectUrl = "https://dev-myaccount.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                         OpenIdConnectScopes = "openid,profile")]
        [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The OK response")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {
```

This does provide the necessary authentication in the swagger UI but there is no audience passed when the token is requested which causes Auth0 to respond with an opaque token which is not in JWT format.

Is there a way to specify the audience and have the swagger UI send that when authenticating?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround is to establishing the `TokenValidationParameters` which uses audience against the values in the ValidIssuer and ValidAudience properties and validating the token issuer.

I'm just highlighting the most significant parts here, but you can refer more from the below link.

```
// Create the parameters
var tokenParams = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
    RequireSignedTokens = true,
    ValidAudience = _audience,
    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidIssuer = _issuer,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidateLifetime = true,
    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(_issuerToken))
};
    
// Validate the token
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var result = handler.ValidateToken(token, tokenParams, out var securityToken);
```

In your function class:-

```
private readonly IAccessTokenProvider _tokenProvider;
    
    public SampleFunction(IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    [FunctionName("SampleFunction")]
    public IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,  ILogger log)
    {
        var result = _tokenProvider.ValidateToken(req);
    
        if (result.Status == AccessTokenStatus.Valid)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Request received for {result.Principal.Identity.Name}.");
            return new OkResult();
        }
        else
        {
            return new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
```

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Custom token authentication in Azure Functions](https://www.ben-morris.com/custom-token-authentication-in-azure-functions-using-bindings/)
2. [Making a CRUD API using Azure Functions](https://auth0.com/blog/making-crud-api-with-azure-functions/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm specifically trying to figure out if there is a way of making the OpenAPI generated swagger UI send the audience. Its not clear to me from what you provide how I would acheive that.

Comment: Are you trying to send audience data through Azure Function's swagger decoration?

Comment: Yes, I need the generated swagger UI to send an audience when I use that UI to authenticate in order to then execute API methods from the swagger UI.